# Anatomically Correct Makara

Tags: creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct

The makara is a river-dwelling mount with an odd appearance. Overall, it resembles a crocodile, with a few distinct traits: Its face has an elephant-like trunk, and round ears like a mouse. It also has a few longer teeth, resembling pig tusks. Its feet are leonine, with the legs being more crocodilian. Its skin is covered in fish-like scales, and above its tail is a large peacock train. It is domesticated for riding

How could such a creature arise?

Comment: What are it's natural characteristics and behaviour as per the [anatomically correct series specs](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The makara could be a crocodilian of some sort

If it were more herbivorous, a prehensile nose/lip would help it to eat the plants more easily: This could result in the development of a trunk

The mouse ears and pig tusks could be explained as display structures, as they would be nuisances that demonstrate the animal's ability to survive. Similarly, the train could be a display structure, developed from scales that have taken on a hair-like form

The fish scales could be a form of agressive mimicry used to attract animals too small to apreciate its full form, allowing it an easy snack, or perhaps driving away parasites

The leonine paws could have originated as a more unique paw design, allowing the makara to run with more force, before being bred into a more prestigious lion paw. This could also have happened with the train